# Dealing with directory path spaces in batch script with for /D loop

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I see a lot of scripts online using `for /f "delims="` to deal with spaces in paths when looping through directories, but I can't seem to find anything that handles this when it's a `for /D` loop.

Perhaps `for /f "delims="` is a more desirable solution, but the inability to get `for /D` to work is bothering me nonetheless.

**Example:**

```
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    echo %%d\test.txt
)
```

Comment: and what exactly is the issue? if the directory name has spaces in it they should be displayed ....

Comment: @npocmaka When I'm acting on the same example, a file within said `%%d` that contains spaces will fail with it not being found. No issues with the `delims` method I see online though.

Comment: echo will not print `not being found` - you are probably usong some other command. Try to enclose the result in quotes - `echo "%%d\test.txt"`

Comment: @npocmaka I'd never said it was verbatim alerting "not being found". It was "The system cannot find the file specified". I've enclosed the path in double quotes and it seems to work. Initially, I'd tried using single quotes without success.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of my example code above, enclosing the path in double quotes, per @npocmaka's suggestion was the fix to the issue.

**Example:**

```
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    echo "%%d\test.txt"
)
```